# Script is not putting events into other form submitters calendars

Tags: forms, google-apps-script, permissions, calendar, google-calendar-api

Please can somebody help. I am using the following script to create calendar events from form submission. When I submit the form the event goes into the relevant calendars (the form submitters and the centre the form relates to). When a different user submits the form the calendar even isn't created. The form submitters email address is the calendar ID and their calendar is fully visible to me (permissions have been checked). The trigger runs without error (shows as completed) but the execution log has the message;

Aug 16, 2023, 12:57:48 PM   Info    User's calendar not found.

Can anyone help me to fix it please?

```
function createCalendarEvent(e) {
  var formResponse = e.response;
  var itemResponses = formResponse.getItemResponses();

  // Check the response for the question "What are you doing today?"
  var activityQuestion = "What are you doing today?";
  var activityResponse = getFormResponseByTitle(itemResponses, activityQuestion);

  if (activityResponse === "Reviewing actions") {
    // If the response is "Reviewing actions", do not create a calendar event
    return;
  }

  var form = FormApp.getActiveForm();
  var formTitle = form.getTitle();

  // Adjust the following values to match the question titles in your form
  var dateQuestion = "Date actions will be reviewed";
  var startTimeQuestion = "Review Start Time";
  var endTimeQuestion = "Review End Time";
  var centreNameQuestion = "Centre Name";
  var centreNumberQuestion = "Centre Number";

  var eventTitle = "AOM Productive Visit actions review - ";
  var eventDescription = "";

  var date = "";
  var startTime = "";
  var endTime = "";
  var centreName = "";
  var centreNumber = "";

  // Retrieve the date, start time, end time, centre name, and centre number from the form responses
  date = getFormResponseByTitle(itemResponses, dateQuestion);
  startTime = getFormResponseByTitle(itemResponses, startTimeQuestion);
  endTime = getFormResponseByTitle(itemResponses, endTimeQuestion);
  centreName = getFormResponseByTitle(itemResponses, centreNameQuestion);
  centreNumber = getFormResponseByTitle(itemResponses, centreNumberQuestion);

  // Merge the date, start time, and end time into datetime values
  var startDateTimeString = date + " " + startTime;
  var endDateTimeString = date + " " + endTime;
  var startDateTime = new Date(startDateTimeString);
  var endDateTime = new Date(endDateTimeString);

  // Create the calendar event
  var eventTitleWithCentre = eventTitle + centreName;

  // Get the form submitter's email from the form response
  var userEmail = e.response.getRespondentEmail();

  // Get the user's calendar
  var calendars = CalendarApp.getOwnedCalendarsByName(userEmail);
  var userCalendar = (calendars.length > 0) ? calendars[0] : null;

  if (!userCalendar) {
    Logger.log("User's calendar not found.");
    return;
  }

  // Add the link to the submitted form in the event description
  eventDescription +=
    "**Please click on the following link to review the actions from your centre visit -**\n" +
    "https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/15xJKC5_HAC6sDoZhhOV7fFK5knQ-mKBH?usp=drive_link" + "\n\n";

  // Create the calendar event with the updated event description on the user's calendar
  var event = userCalendar.createEvent(eventTitleWithCentre, startDateTime, endDateTime, { description: eventDescription });

  // Invite the center to the event
  var centreEmail = centreNumber + "mgr01@xxxxxxxxxx.com";
  event.addGuest(centreEmail);
}

// Function to get the form response by question title
function getFormResponseByTitle(itemResponses, questionTitle) {
  for (var i = 0; i < itemResponses.length; i++) {
    var itemResponse = itemResponses[i];
    var title = itemResponse.getItem().getTitle();
    if (title === questionTitle) {
      return itemResponse.getResponse();
    }
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand the relationship between `The form submitters email address is the calendar ID and their calendar is fully visible to me (permissions have been checked). The trigger runs without error (shows as completed)` and `Aug 16, 2023, 12:57:48 PM Info User's calendar not found.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: `var calendars = CalendarApp.getOwnedCalendarsByName(userEmail)` is returning null because `getOwnedCalendarsByName(name)` "gets all calendars _with a given name_ that **the user** owns" (my emphasis). The calendar data in this section of code isn't tied/linked to form response data. This is why it is working for you (because _you_ are the user) but not for other respondents. I'm sorry that (at this stage) I don't have a work-around but I thought it was better to explain the cause of the problem asap.

Comment: Why not just use `var userCalendar =CalendarApp.getCalendarById(userEmail);`? And drop `var calendars` as well as `if (!userCalendar) {`.